# MySQL how to get user rank by votes amount

Tags: php, mysql

I have two tables. One "user" and one "votes", each user can have n votes. Now I select a list of users and output it.
It works well with votes as COUNT in a LEFT JOIN, but now I want to calculate the RANK (1st, 2nd, 3rth, ...) of the user.

Theoretically very easy with ORDER BY Votes, but I also allow my users to SORT BY user date (when they joined). And I also have a pagination with a LIMIT in my query. So how do I solve this as best?

```
$user_sql   = $db->query("SELECT u.*, COUNT(v.voteId) AS user_votes 
                          FROM cs_users AS u
                          LEFT JOIN cs_users_votes AS v 
                          ON u.userId = v.voteUserId");
```

(Basic query, but with pagination and sorter ORDER BY / LIMIT etc. will be added)

Hope you can help!

Comment: i am confused about " but I also allow my users to SORT BY user date (when they joined)."???

Comment: I mean, when I SORT BY user Date I can't use the order of the MySQL Output to get the rank, like counting $i++; every user, to get rank. Same problem when using LIMIT

Comment: rank is based on votes?

Comment: did you try this 
SELECT u.*, COUNT(v.voteId) AS user_votes 
                          FROM cs_users AS u
                          LEFT JOIN cs_users_votes AS v 
                          ON u.userId = v.voteUserId order by votes desc, date desc;

Comment: @habibulhaq how it will display RANK?

Comment: @habibulhaq I dont get it how it shall display me Rank...

Comment: @Maxi can you tell me what you get the result of your query??

Comment: try this 
SELECT u.*, COUNT(v.voteId) AS user_votes 
                          FROM cs_users AS u
                          LEFT JOIN cs_users_votes AS v 
                          ON u.userId = v.voteUserId
group by v.user_id  order by count(v.voteUserid) desc limit 3

Comment: Use one of the solutions from this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1895110/row-number-in-mysql, and use the query as a subquery to get desired sorting.

Comment: I think you should explain more about how you handle pagination.

Answer (score 0):

Well, to count rank you can use the ranking function found [here](http://fellowtuts.com/mysql/query-to-obtain-rank-function-in-mysql/)
It will rank every user, taking in consideration result ties. If you add pagination you might try to pass the result from the previous page recursively.

As for the function itself

```
SET @curRank :=0, @prevRank := NULL;
SELECT u.*, COUNT(v.voteId) AS user_votes,
CASE 
WHEN @prevRank = id THEN @curRank 
WHEN @prevRank := id THEN @curRank := @curRank + 1
END AS rank
FROM cs_users AS u
LEFT JOIN cs_users_votes AS v 
ON u.userId = v.voteUserId
```

Comment: Good, but I think you've forgotten the ORDER BY and LIMIT part. What impact will the OP's pagination method have on this query?

Comment: Yes. I just wanted to show the idea of ranking itself, not to give an exact solution.
About pagination - there are several solutions - personally I would make a TEMP table with all the RANKS, using the query I have given, and then adding pagination to it. 
Table itself can be rebuild e.g. hourly or based on events (e.g. new vote). This will dramatically increase query speed as well, as there won't be a necessity to make any JOINs, just a query from a plain table